# SQLite: Is it possible to change the typeof(A VALUE) from 'integer' to 'text'?

Tags: sqlite, casting, rsqlite

Background:  I find that when I imported a *.csv file into SQLite (using RSQLite) a few values in a text affinity column got stored as 'integer' values.  Unfortunately the value of the first row of that column is one of those "integer" values.  Now, when I then extract that column into R (using RSQLite), I get a nice message that the column is mixed type, but the first value encountered is numeric, so all the rest of the values are coerced to type numeric (which winds up as 0).
Question:  Is there a way to change the storage type of a value once it is in SQLite?  I have tried:
update table XXX set YYY to (cast YYY as text) where typeof(YYY) = 'integer';
But that doesn't seem to change anything.
Any suggestions deeply appreciated.
Larry Hunsicker

Comment: You're going to have to give more details here.  I've just made a little experiment and found (1) that if I create a table with a column of TEXT type that `INSERT INTO XXX VALUES(1);` results in `'1'` being inserted, not `1`, as expected, and (2) if I  create a table *without* affinity and do the same, `1` is inserted but `UPDATE XXX SET YYY=CAST(YYY AS TEXT);` results a `'1'`.  You're doing something wrong, but I can't tell from your description what.

Comment: It is not possible for a text affinity column to contain unwanted integers. Show the actual table definition.

Comment: Could you please share a version of your CSV file, and the code you use to write/read?

Comment: Varro:  I created a new table and have confirmed that the UPDATE works as expected in this new database, but not in my previous database.  No-one else is using the database, and there are no keys (primary or foreign) that use the field.  I'm sort of stuck.

Comment: CL:  It's a very long table definition.  But the field is simply declared as "_Name_ integer,"  No keys or indices on the field.
Krlmlr:  It's a huge file with data that I am not free to share.  So far I have not been able to create a new csv file that shows this problem.